# XAML/WPF WebBrowser Event Not Firing

Tags: c#, xaml

I'm using XAML/WPF/C# and create a WebBrowser control on a XAML Window as follows:

```
    <Border Background="Transparent" BorderBrush="White" BorderThickness="1" >
        <WebBrowser ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled"
                        ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled"
                        ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll="False"
                        HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
                        VerticalAlignment="Stretch" 
                        LoadCompleted="AfterpageDraw"
                        Name="SpecialForm"  />
    </Border>
```

In the c# code, the WebBrowser is loaded with an html page:

```
this.SpecialForm.NavigateToString(path2page);
mshtml.IHTMLDocument3 htmlDoc = (mshtml.IHTMLDocument3)this.SpecialForm.Document;
```

I have a `<select>` element on the page that is loaded and it has an onclick event with javascript method assigned.  The page is working fine outside in a standard browser window.  The onclick event method isn't called though when loaded into the WebBrowser control.

```
<select onclick="multiselect('xxx')" id="myselect" name="myselect">
    <option value="">Select a value</option>
    <option value="Num1">Num 1</option>
    <option value="Num2">Num 2</option>
    <option value="Num3">Num 3</option>
    <option value="Num4">Num 4</option>
</select>
```

In the c# code I can locate the select object, an object of type mshtml.IHTMLElement.  When the page is initialized, in the debugger I can see that the value of select.onclick parameter is set to "multiselect('xxx')".

I'm not sure how to debug the web page in the WebBrowser control.

After some research I found some info from around 2004 that says that the WebBrowser element doesn't support mouse events.

I tried the following, which obviously won't work, because this invokes the Javascript method immediately rather than calling the method on mouse click, although I do see that the javascript is available on the page and runs.

```
select.onclick = this.SpecialForm.InvokeScript("multiselect", new String[] { attrName });
```

How can I assign a Javascript onclick event handler to an IHTMLElement element?